# Trying to understand Sorting in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was recently going through some sorting algorithms including Bubble Sort, Selection Sort, Insertion Sort, Merge Sort, Heap Sort, Quick Sort etc., when suddenly a question aroused in my mind that when we use the function sort() in Java or any other language which Sorting algorithm does it follows?and is the sorting function's algorithm same for all other languages?

For example this is my code in Java :

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

   public class ArrayDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   int i;
   int A[] = {2, 1, 9, 6, 4};


   for (i = 0; i < A.length ; i++)
   {
   System.out.println("Number = " + A[i]);
   }

   // sorting array
   Arrays.sort(A);


   System.out.println("The sorted int array is:");
   for (i = 0; i < A.length ; i++)
   {
      System.out.println("Number = " + A[i]);
   }
   }
}
```

and, I want to know which Sorting Algorithm does Arrays.sort() use to sort the Array A.

Thanks

Comment: See the [documentation for java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html), they use the DualPivotQuicksort algorithm.

```
/**
65        * Sorts the specified array into ascending numerical order.
66        *
67        * <p>Implementation note: The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot     Quicksort
68        * by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This  algorithm
69        * offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other
70        * quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically
71        * faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.
72        *
73        * @param a the array to be sorted
74        */
75       public static void sort(int[] a) {
76           DualPivotQuicksort.sort(a);
77       }
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, a variation of quick sort for an array of primitives, and a variation of merge sort for an array of objects (stability, and since objects are typically implemented internally as pointers to objects, merge sort should be faster),

Comment: @rcgldr The variation on mergesort is described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort.